# How to read the https page content using java?

Tags: java

How to read the https page content using java??

Comment: As an example, you can use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/), but you have to be more specific. Where you are trying to read it from? URL? file?

Comment: This question is way to broad and should be closed if the OP does not provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

Following is an example of retrieving the content of the page for  "https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html"  It works for any page that have https protocol only if a login is NOT required.  Just replace the httpsURL string.  Enjoy!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

/**
 * <b>Get the Html source from a https url </b>
 */
public class HttpsClientUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String httpsURL = "https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html";

        URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty ( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0" );
        InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried it. It works!