# Java - Read page source from url returns unknown characters

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the code below to read a page source from url (https://www.amazon.com) with "UTF-8" charset in NetBeans, but it returns unknown characters (the attached image). I don't have any idea that what is the problem and would be gratefull if help me to modify the code to work properly? Thanks.

[image]

```
public static String getURLSource(String url) throws IOException
{
    URL urlObject = new URL(url);
    URLConnection urlConnection = urlObject.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");

    return toString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
}

private static String toString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
{
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")))
    {
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you're seeing the encrypted payload. You need to use some sort of an HTTPS client to handle the exchange of keys, the validation of the server's cert and - most importantly - the decoding of the stream.

Comment: @skomisa thanks for the answer. I have uncommented that line in my code.

Comment: @skomisa thanks for the answer. It was just a typo and I have uncommented that line in my code (the problem is not related to that!).

Comment: @Mr.Nobody I also tried reading Amazon's home page [using JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) with limited success. There are some [JSoup examples here which use Amazon's home page](https://able.bio/DavidLandup/introduction-to-web-scraping-with-java-jsoup--641yfyl). It seems that Amazon deliberately do not make it easy to scrape their pages.

Comment: Thanks again @skomisa , I will try using 'Jsoup'.

Comment: could it be you are receiving gzipped data?

Comment: @Wolfgang Thanks for comment. I don't know!

Comment: @Mr.Nobody Yes you definitely receive zipped data. See my answer, it gives you the code how to unzip it. I ran it and got the clear text of the amazon page

Answer (score 1):

Use `HttpsUrlConnection` instead of `UrlConnection`. See [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155488/how-to-read-the-https-page-content-using-java).

Comment: I have already examined it with 'HttpsUrlConnection', but nothing changed!

Comment: @skomisa Sorry, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to unzip your content. Here is the code that worked for me

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
try {
    httpClient.setConnectionUrl("https://www.amazon.com");
    ByteBuffer buff = httpClient.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11")
            .sendHttpRequestForBinaryResponse(HttpClient.HttpMethod.GET);
    try (
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(buff.array());
            GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(bais);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(gzis);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)
    ) {
        br.lines().forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(httpClient.getLastResponseCode() + " "
            + httpClient.getLastResponseMessage() + TextUtils.getStacktrace(e, false));
}
```

Just few clarifications: In this example I use a 3d party Http client class `HttpClient` (And also class `TextUtils`). They both come from Open source MgntUtils library writen and maintained by me. But you don't have to use it. The main part is - read the info from the `InputStream` as binary info (as byte array or ByteBuffer) and than and unzip it with `GZIPInputStream` like in my example.

If you do want to use MgntUtils library you can get it As [maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc). and here is [Javadoc online](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/)