# Why I can not read some https pages with java code?

Tags: java, https, httpsurlconnection

I write a java program like I saw here
[How to read the https page content using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155488/how-to-read-the-https-page-content-using-java)
but for some sites the code does not work.

I got Error Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://research.investors.com/stock-quotes/nyse-sailpoint-tech-holdings-sail.htm

It works for
url = "https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html";

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

> **403 Forbidden**
> The request contained valid data and was understood by the server, but the server is refusing action. This may be due to the user not having the necessary permissions for a resource or needing an account of some sort, or attempting a prohibited action (e.g. creating a duplicate record where only one is allowed). This code is also typically used if the request provided authentication by answering the WWW-Authenticate header field challenge, but the server did not accept that authentication. The request should not be repeated.

So probably website, which you want to **scrape**, just restricted requests like yours (i mean requests, that was made not from browser).

But you can try [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/).

Answer (score 1):

[403 HTTP status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) stands for "Forbidden", most likely investors.com can check your request headers and deny the resource.

Try modifying the request headers using an `User-Agent` that site might accept.

Answer (score 0):

OK , I solved.
I use con.setRequestProperty and set "User-Agent", "Accept", "Content-Type", "Accept-Language".

Thank you.